# Ubuntu/Debian dependencies for packaging mono gtk# application

Tags: c#, deployment, ubuntu, mono, gtk#

I am packaging my Mono GTK# application for Ubuntu/Debian (.deb).

- How do I find out which dependencies to list in the control file?
- Which are the standard ones, for mono and gtk# themselves? Is it the ones ending in -dev?

I have looked in the Debian packaging docs, but those examples seem overly complicated with post-installation hooks etc.

The examples in the mono documentation mostly concern source distributions with automake etc. I just want to put binaries in there.

Answer (score 3):

I have just gone through the process of packaging my GTK# mono application (Wide Margin) for debian.

Here is my control file:

```
Source: widemargin
Section: gnome
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Debian CLI Applications Team <pkg-cli-apps-team@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Uploaders: Daniel Hughes <trampster@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~), cli-common-dev (>= 0.7.1), mono-xbuild (>= 2.6.7), libgtk2.0-cil-dev (>= 2.12.10), mono-devel (>= 2.6.7), libglade2.0-cil-dev (>= 2.12.10)
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Homepage: https://bitbucket.org/trampster/widemargin
Vcs-Git: git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-cli-apps/packages/widemargin.git
Vcs-Browser: http://git.debian.org/?p=pkg-cli-apps/packages/widemargin.git

Package: widemargin
Architecture: all
Depends: ${cli:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: bible reading and study application
 Wide Margin is a bible reading and study application. It has a focus on
 speed and simplicity. Features include, as you type searching and passage
 navigation, familiar browser based interface, full navigation history and 
 a built in reading planner which will have you read the old testament 
 once and the new testament twice every year.
```

The important thing to note here is that if you use ${cli:Depends}, ${misc:Depends} in your Depends section the dependencies will be auto-magically sorted out for you.
You will however have to set your Build-Depends manually.

The second tip is to get onto the #debian-cli irc channel, it contains all the mono packagers for debain. They are super helpful and will sponsor you package for you when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why do you include xbuild into Build-Depends? Does this package contain source code? And does the ${cli:Depends}, ${misc:Depends} trick also work with pre-compiled binaries?

Comment: Xbuild is mono's version of msbuild. It's what I use to build my binaries. And yes my package is built from source (if you want it in debain it needs to be that way). I don't know the answer to your last question I would jump onto the @debian-cli irc channel and ask there.

Comment: Ok, so as i mentioned I want to package binaries. It is not meant to be a package for the Debian repositories, I will distribute myself. But thanks for your tip I will ask around there, perhaps I can return a favor.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Mono

I haven't yet tried it myself but it seems concise so far.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said I looked at these docs. On dependencies, the one you links says: "This guide assumes that you know what mono libraries are required to build the package. In this example, you need libgtk2.0-cil-dev, libvte0.16-cil-dev, libwebkit-cil-dev . So you add them to the build-depends line in the control file." So how do I know whether these also apply to my application?

Comment: If your application compiles, you already have all the info you need. E.g. if your command line compile or monodevelop solution includes `gkeyfile-sharp` you could issue a `dpkg -S gkeyfile-sharp.dll` to get the name of the runtime package and a `dpkg -S gkeyfile-sharp.pc` to get the development package.

Comment: And would I distribute the development package or the runtime package?